# Prevent submit while jQuery effect is running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this issue that when user clicks a button (in this case, a submit button) multiple times, jQuery will keep playing the animation effects until it has completed the count of clicks the user has imputed.

This can get quite overwhelming.

**How can jQuery tell if it's currently executing an animation to a particular element, so I can prevent user from submitting while the elements effect is still in play?**

Notes: the submit button is in a file. Form handling is relayed via AJAX this jQuery is inside the ajax called file.

Here is the main files code:

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
        $.post(
               "ajax.php",
               { user: $('[name="username"]').val(), pw: $('[name="password"]').val() },
               function(resposeText) { $('#login_form_response').html(resposeText); },
               "html"
               );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here is the code (in ajax'ed' file):

```
$('#login_form_response').html('Username or Password is inaccurate!')
.slideDown()
.delay(3500)
.slideUp(1500);
```

Comment: Do you want to **prevent** the submission? or to **delay** it until the animation is finished?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, jQuery delays the second animation until the first animation is complete. I want to prevent the second animation completely!

Answer (score 7):

You could unbind the event-handler just before starting the animation, and in the callback function of the animation, just bind the handler again.

```
$('#button').unbind('click');

$('#animated_element').animate({ animation, stuff}, 1000, function(){
   $('#button').bind('click', handlerFunc);
});
```

**Note:**

This is a way to prevent submitting when you are using a *customized* button (div, or a link), which has an event handler binded to it. It does not work on pure html `<input type="submit" />` - buttons, because after unbinding, the standard-submit is going to take effect. 
I prefer to use customized buttons, mainly because of styling (especially for IE7 and such).

If you want to use a pure html-submit button, you'll have to disable the button (and disabling submit over "enter") or set a flag, that prevents submitting, as other users have already stated in their answers!

Comment: Interesting, I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: This answer's code is missing the second single quotation mark `'` on `'#animated_element'`.

Comment: Alright, my bad. I always use customized buttons, when JavaScript is enabled to submit forms. In this case, you'll have to disable the button too, in order to prevent standard-submission, or place an "onsubmit=return false" in the form.

Comment: unbinding a click to button wont stop form submission (unless button is explicitly asked to do so). check this demo , http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/cfvRf/1/ , click unbind still form submits

Answer (score 5):

Disable the submit button until the animation finishes.

```
$('animatingElementSelector').animate({height: 200px;}, slow, function() { //ENABLE BUTTON HERE });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var isAnimationRunning;


jQuery('#myForm').bind('submit',function(e){

   if(isAnimationRunning)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Create a variable `isAnimationRunning` let it know, animation running or not. If running then ignore submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/cfvRf/

On demo click start animation and then try to submit!!

**Edit 1**

Some ppl have suggested unbinding click of submit button, that wont work. If a submit button is inside a form, clicking it will submit the form, you dont bind click event to submit form, its just pure html, so unbinding wont help in stopping submit event. [check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/cfvRf/1/)

**Edit 2**
Some ppl have suggested disable the submit button during the animation. That wont **always** work either, consider a situation where user types something in text box and press enter key, form will be submitted(some browsers will) regardless of submit button being disabled.

Comment: Yisroel: that's the only way to do, even disabling the submit wont help either. read the edit2

Answer (score 0):

Just add disabling button when it clicked :) or hide... or both of this... hide and disable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('style','opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50); ');
        $.post(
               "ajax.php",
               { user: $('[name="username"]').val(), pw: $('[name="password"]').val() },
               function(resposeText) { $('#login_form_response').html(resposeText); },
               "html"
               );
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```